# Tensorflow 2.0.0 MirroredStrategy NCCL problem

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to train with multi-gpu using tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy().

After several attempt to apply to my custom code, it has some error about NcclAllReduce.

So I copied mnist tutorial using tf.distribute from tensorflow page, running it has same error. logs and my environments are below

> My env
>   sys.platform----------Window 10
>
> Python----------3.7.6
>
> Numpy----------1.18.1
>
> TensorFlow----------2.0.0
>
> TF CUDA support-----------True
>
> GPU----------2 GPU, both are Quadro GV100

```
INFO:tensorflow:batch_all_reduce: 8 all-reduces with algorithm = nccl, num_packs = 1, agg_small_grads_max_bytes = 0 and agg_small_grads_max_group = 10
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:batch_all_reduce: 8 all-reduces with algorithm = nccl, num_packs = 1, agg_small_grads_max_bytes = 0 and agg_small_grads_max_group = 10
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a7ead7e91ea5> in <module>
     19     num_batches = 0
     20     for x in train_dist_dataset:
---> 21       total_loss += distributed_train_step(x)
     22       num_batches += 1
     23     train_loss = total_loss / num_batches

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-MSTO-DL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-MSTO-DL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    518         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    519         # stateless function.
--> 520         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    521     else:
    522       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-MSTO-DL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824 
   1825   @property

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-MSTO-DL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142 
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-MSTO-DL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-MSTO-DL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-MSTO-DL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf-MSTO-DL\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'NcclAllReduce' used by {{node Adam/NcclAllReduce}}with these attrs: [reduction="sum", shared_name="c1", T=DT_FLOAT, num_devices=2]
Registered devices: [CPU, GPU]
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[Adam/NcclAllReduce]] [Op:__inference_distributed_train_step_1755]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for `cross_device_ops`, it seems

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(
     cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.NcclAllReduce())
```

would produce a NCCL error depending on your architecture and configuration.

This option was meant for NVIDIA DGX-1 architecture and might underperform on other architectures :

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(
    cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce())
```

Should work :

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(
     cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.ReductionToOneDevice())
```

So that it can be advised to try the different options.

See [Tensorflow Multi-GPU - NCCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973491/tensorflow-multi-gpu-nccl/68908256#68908256)

Answer (score 1):

NCCL drivers do not work with Windows. To my knowledge they only work with Linux. I have read that there might be a NCCL driver equivalent for Windows but have not been able to find them myself. If you want to stay with Windows you can try `HierarchicalCopyAllReduce`.

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1"],
                    cross_device_ops = tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce())
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
```

Comment: What difference does using different reduce algorithms? For example, how do I decide which one to use in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
```

For me (1 CPU - 3 GPU setup on Windows WSL2) it's faster than any of the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with tensorflow 2.2.0 when using tf.distribbute.MirrorStrategy and found that I was running the wrong version of Cuda - I had been runing 10.0 and it should have been cuda 10.1.

I think worth checking which version you are running and if it's right.

For tensorflow 2.0.0 you should be using cuda 10.0. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations) for combinations between the two libraries