# Keras multi GPU using Tensorflow MirroredStrategy

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, multi-gpu

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=100, restore_best_weights=True, verbose=0)
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=['/gpu:0', '/gpu:1', '/gpu:2', '/gpu:3'])
with strategy.scope():
   model = RESNET()
history = model.fit(samples2Fit, validation_data=samples2Validate, epochs=args.epochs, callbacks=[es], verbose=0)
```

The `RESNET()` model is compiled as: `model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(epsilon=1e-08), metrics=[tf.keras.losses.Huber()])` and all other modules are also from `tensorflow.keras.**`

When I run this using 4 GPUs I get the following error: ValueError: Please use `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM` or `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE` for loss reduction when losses are used with `tf.distribute.Strategy` outside of the built-in training loops...

I am following the example given in https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/ so what am I missing and why do I need to use these reductions? What is meant by *outside of the built-in training loops*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106201/tensorflow-2-0-0-mirroredstrategy-nccl-problem/68917490#68917490

Answer (score 0):

try fitting within the strategy scope

```
with strategy.scope():
   model = RESNET()
   history = model.fit(samples2Fit, validation_data=samples2Validate, 
         epochs=args.epochs, callbacks=[es], verbose=0)
```

by default `MirroredStrategy` will use `cross_device_ops` with `NcclAllReduce()`

> cross_device_ops: optional, a descedant of CrossDeviceOps. If this is
> not set, NcclAllReduce() will be used by default. One would customize
> this if NCCL isn't available or if a special implementation that
> exploits the particular hardware is available.

you might try different `cross_device_ops` options https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy